# kramdown does not format tables

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

Using kramdown version 1.10.0, I am trying to figure out how to get it to render a table.  In any of the markdown formats.

I've tried the following:

```
foo | bar

| foo | bar |


|-----+-----|
| foo | bar |
|-----+-----|
```

However, none of those seem to render using kramdown.

This is particularly frustrating as I'm trying to show a table in jekyll.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, which was two-fold:

1. Tables are rendered without a border, so it was easy to miss.
2. I was using an 'html' file extension, rather than markdown.  A classic newbie problem.